# passing password automatically in a schedule task

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I created a schedule task in XP for running a program everyday. It works great. But it needs a username and password for log in. How I can give this log in details automatically after the log in window prompt for userid and password.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> Properties -> Tab Task -> Run as username/password
```

If the existing prompt is disabled, creating a new task should help. The wizard will ask for username&password.